# Including special relativistic effects in momentum in Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, momentum, electrons, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I've been told that an electron is somewhere within the space of $10^{-10}m$ and am supposed to find the uncertainty in its velocity.

Simply applying $m\Delta x \Delta v \geq \frac{h}{4\pi}$ results in $\Delta v \geq 5.79\times10^{10} m/s$. Now, this velocity is not approaching the speed of light, but I wanted to know if I could use the Lorentz factor to make this calculation more accurate (of course in this situation it would not make much of a difference.

So I redefined momentum uncertainty as $\Delta p = \gamma m_0 \Delta v$ and solved the inequality... but my final answer states $\Delta v \leq 3\times10^8$... this relation is obvious... but why has it popped out of this?

What if the space was even smaller when  special relativistic effects actually would come into play, how would I then tackle the question?